# I'm new to Java. How do I correct this code?

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out why my code is not working. The code is below

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
     Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
      String element;
    String elementsymbol;
    System.out.println("Element Name : ");
    element = reader.nextString();
    if (element.equals("Gold"));
        elementsymbol.equals("Au");
        System.out.println("Element Symbol : " + elementsymbol);
 if (element.equals("Silver"));
        elementsymbol.equals("Ag");
        System.out.println("Element Symbol : " + elementsymbol);
    if (element.equals("Platinum"));
        elementsymbol.equals("Pt");
       System.out.println("Element Symbol : " + elementsymbol);


  }
}
```

The error is

```
Main.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    element = reader.nextString();
                    ^
  symbol:   method nextString()
  location: variable reader of type Scanner
1 error
compiler exit status 1
```

Everything seems to be right but I'm not so sure anymore. 
Thanks

Comment: The error is unrelated to the code

Comment: There is no **reader.nextString();**  Kindly use **reader.nextLine()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scanner has no method nextString
try using

> `reader.nextLine()`

this listens from the keyboard until enter key is pressed

Also

> elementsymbol.equals("Au");

does not assign "Au" to elementSymbol it returns a boolean value instead. Therefore the value of elementSymbol is always null.

try using

> elementsymbol = "Au";

Comment: Thank you for the help, it fixed the problem i had but created a problem with my display.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Scanner` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) have never mentioned any method called `nextString()`.

You're looking for [`Scanner.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--):

```
element = reader.nextLine();
```

---

While a bit outside the scope of the question, you also appear to have a few misunderstandings about the proper syntax for the `if` control structure, which I would recommend brushing up on in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html). In other words, I'm not sure if your `if` statements (the way you've presented them) will follow a flow that you'd expect.